# kotlin android - Xposed IllegalArgumentException 'android.content.res.CoollifeUITpedArray'

Tags: android, kotlin

How to solve this error
Xposed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot transfer object from class android.content.res.CoollifeUITypedArray to class android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray

```
E/Xposed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot transfer object from class android.content.res.CoollifeUITypedArray to class android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.setObjectClass(XposedBridge.java:468)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedInit$10.afterHookedMethod(XposedInit.java:353)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:348)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.<init>(<Xposed>)
    at android.content.res.CoollifeUITypedArray.<init>(CoollifeUITypedArray.java:14)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.obtain(TypedArray.java:66)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1838)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:537)
    at android.transition.Transition.<init>(Transition.java:270)
    at android.transition.TransitionSet.<init>(TransitionSet.java:85)
    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml(TransitionInflater.java:169)
    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.inflateTransition(TransitionInflater.java:79)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getTransition(PhoneWindow.java:4237)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4198)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2031)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:379)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.info.edudharma.activities.Activity_Main.onCreate(Activity_Main.java:125)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1114)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2537)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2672)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1495)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

Comment: Please add the code where this happens.

Comment: my application all activity and fragment..
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Comment: Looks like an issue with Xposed method hooking. Disable all Xposed mods, that should solve this issue.

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann it working errors gone ..thank you...